# sql query - update fields in existing with record values in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Environment: SQL Server 2012

I have a transaction table that contains a group of records with group id column.

In the example illustrated below, group 2 records were copied from group 1 records, Except for the sideId, sideSort, topId and topSort columns. Is there a way to cascade that down from group 1 to group 2 `for just topSort and sideSort`? The hard part is that topId and sideId aren't the same because of Identity fields in parent tables.

Here is a [sqlfiddle of the example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/328c0/29)

[image]

Comment: Is there a specific relationship between group1's topId values and group2's TopID values?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I mean, visually you can see that top Id 3 came from top Id 1 and 4 came from 2, maybe?

Comment: That's not a very good indication... Why were those columns not copied from the original records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `Id` is an order field in the Group:

```
WITH C as 
(
  select Tracker.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GroupId ORDER BY Id) as RN
  FROM Tracker  
)  
UPDATE CT 
SET CT.topSort=CTU.topSort,
    CT.sideSort=CTU.sideSort

FROM C as CT
JOIN C as CTU ON (CT.rn=CTU.rn) 
                  and (CTU.GroupID=1)
WHERE CT.GroupID=2
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6b9f0/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way. This is based on the assumption that you copy all the records for one group (`@copiedFromGroupId`) to another (`@copiedToGroupId`), i.e. that the ID's will be shifted by the number of records in the first group.

```
declare @copiedFromGroupId int = 1
declare @copiedToGroupId int = 2
declare @shift int

select @shift = (select max(id) from Tracker where GroupId = @copiedToGroupId) 
  - (select max(id) from Tracker where GroupId = @copiedFromGroupId)

UPDATE T1
SET 
  T1.TopSort = T2.TopSort,
  T1.SideSort = T2.SideSort
FROM Tracker T1
INNER JOIN Tracker T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID + @shift
```

Check this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/328c0/37)

Answer (score 1):

This is based on the row_number over the ORDER of TopId and SortID columns:

```
update test
set test.topSort = mix.topSort, test.sideSort = mix.sideSort
from
(select a.groupid aGroupid, b.groupID, b.Id bID, a.topSort, a.sideSort
from (select groupid, 
     row_number() over(order by topID, sideId) rn,
     topSort, sideSort,
     id
     from test where groupid=1) a
inner join  
     (select groupid, 
     row_number() over(order by topID, sideId) rn,
     topSort, sideSort,
     id
     from test where groupid=2) b ON a.rn = b.rn) mix
inner join test on test.id=mix.bId
WHERE test.groupid=2;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c53c4/2)